# Cassandra: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM on a specific keyspace

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, kibana

Actually, I'm using Elassandra which is a combination of Cassandra and Elasticsearch.
but the issue might came from Cassandra (from the logs said)

I have two nodes joined as a single datacenter DC1. And I'm trying to install Kibana on one of the node. My Kibana server always says "Kibana server is not ready yet" then I've found that the error is something around *Cassandra consistency level*.

My cassandra system_auth is set to

```
system_auth     
WITH REPLICATION= {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
                     'DC1' :2 };
```

and here is the log from manual trigger Kibana service `/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml`

```
FATAL  [exception] org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve 
consistency level QUORUM :: {"path":"/.kibana_1","query":{"include_type_name":true},"body":"
{\"mappings\":{\"doc\":{\"dynamic\":\"strict\",\"properties\":{\"config\":
{\"dynamic\":\"true\",\"properties\":{\"buildNum\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}},\"migrationVersion\":
{\"dynamic\":\"true\",\"type\":\"object\"},\"type\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"namespace\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"updated_at\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"index-pattern\":{\"properties\":
{\"fieldFormatMap\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"fields\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"intervalName\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"notExpandable\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"sourceFilters\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"timeFieldName\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"title\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"type\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"typeMeta\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}},\"visualization\":{\"properties\":{\"description\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"kibanaSavedObjectMeta\":{\"properties\":{\"searchSourceJSON\":
{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"savedSearchId\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"title\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"uiStateJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"version\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"visState\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"search\":{\"properties\":
{\"columns\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"description\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"hits\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"kibanaSavedObjectMeta\":{\"properties\":{\"searchSourceJSON\":
{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"sort\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"title\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"version\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"}}},\"dashboard\":{\"properties\":{\"description\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"hits\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"kibanaSavedObjectMeta\":{\"properties\":
{\"searchSourceJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"optionsJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"panelsJSON\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"refreshInterval\":{\"properties\":{\"display\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"pause\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"section\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"value\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}},\"timeFrom\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"timeRestore\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"timeTo\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"title\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"uiStateJSON\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"version\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}},\"url\":{\"properties\":
{\"accessCount\":{\"type\":\"long\"},\"accessDate\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"createDate\":
{\"type\":\"date\"},\"url\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"fields\":{\"keyword\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\",\"ignore_above\":2048}}}}},\"server\":{\"properties\":{\"uuid\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}},\"kql-telemetry\":{\"properties\":{\"optInCount\":
{\"type\":\"long\"},\"optOutCount\":{\"type\":\"long\"}}},\"timelion-sheet\":{\"properties\":
{\"description\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"hits\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"kibanaSavedObjectMeta\":
{\"properties\":{\"searchSourceJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"timelion_chart_height\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"timelion_columns\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"timelion_interval\":
{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"timelion_other_interval\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"timelion_rows\":
{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"timelion_sheet\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"title\":
{\"type\":\"text\"},\"version\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}}}}},\"settings\":
{\"number_of_shards\":1,\"auto_expand_replicas\":\"0-1\"}}","statusCode":500,"response":"
{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":
[{\"type\":\"exception\",\"reason\":\"org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: 
Cannot achieve consistency level 
QUORUM\"}],\"type\":\"exception\",\"reason\":\"org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableExcept
ion: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM\",\"caused_by\":
{\"type\":\"unavailable_exception\",\"reason\":\"Cannot achieve consistency level 
QUORUM\"}},\"status\":500}"}
```

there are no any indices named 'kibana_1' or any indices contains word kibana. but there are keyspaces named `"_kibana_1"` and `"_kibana"`

and that cause Kibana service unable to start

```
systemctl status kibana
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-09-10 16:26:14 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 16942 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml (code=exited, status=1
 Main PID: 16942 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 10 16:26:14 ns3053180 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem:

```
system_auth WITH REPLICATION= {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'DC1' :2 };
```

The `SimpleStrategy` class does not accept datacenter/RF pairs as parameters.  It has one parameter, which is simply `replication_factor`:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION= {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' :2 };
```

By contrast, the `NetworkTopologyStrategy` takes the parameters you have provided above:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION= {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' :2 };
```

IMO, there really isn't much of a need for `SimpleStrategy`.  I *never* use it.

Note: If you're going to query at `LOCAL_QUORUM`, you should have at least 3 replicas.  Or at the very least, an odd number capable of computing a majority.  Because *quorum* of 2 is, well, 2.  So querying at quorum with only 2 replicas doesn't really help you.